# Summarizing daily sales of products in Java7 / Java 8

Tags: java, java-8

I have list of products. I want to sum all the data with the same id

```
public class Product {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private double price;
    private int quantity;
.....
}
```

I added the data into a list

```
List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();
        products.add(new Product(1, "x", 100, 4));
        products.add(new Product(4, "y", 200, 2));
        products.add(new Product(4, "y", 50, 5));
        products.add(new Product(8, "k", 50, 1));
        products.add(new Product(10, "m", 1000, 1));
        products.add(new Product(1, "x", 100, 1));
```

So far, I have tried to

```
Map<Integer, Double> productsByNameCategoryType = products.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Product::getId,
                        Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                          Collectors.summarizingDouble(Product::getPrice),
                                p -> p.getSum())
                ));
```

This is too far from my expectation and still trying on it
My expectation of the output is

1, x, 200, 5

4, y, 250, 7

8, k, 50, 1

10, m, 1000, 1

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: @ScaryWombat, I tried it but I couldn't go beyond writing it like this which is very far from my expectaion. Map<Integer, Double> productsByNameCategoryType = products.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Product::getId,
                        Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                                Collectors.summarizingDouble(Product::getPrice),
                                p -> p.getSum())
                ));

Comment: @tresf It sums the price and the quantity while keeping the the product name and id. For example product with id 1 is sold two times. so, sum the product price and sum the quantity sold. Product(1, "x", 100, 4)) and (new Product(1, "x", 100, 1)); The result will be like id 1, name x, price 200, quantity 5. This is the general idea

Comment: Yeah, the question makes sense.  I would recommend streaming into a new list of `Products()` as a container.  If the name is confusing, rename `Products()` to `Sales()`.  Each item would contain the aggregated values, but joined on the `id`.

Comment: Use the _toMap_ method.  _List<Product> l = products.stream().collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toMap(Product::getId, x -> x, (a, b) -> { Product p = new Product(); p.setId(a.getId()); p.setName(a.getName()); p.setPrice(a.getPrice() + b.getPrice()); p.setQuantity(a.getQuantity() + b.getQuantity()); return p; }), x -> new ArrayList<>(x.values())));_

Comment: @Reilas Thank you. That is an easy to understand brave solution.

Comment: @Andy999L, no problem.  I've added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"... I have list of products. I want to sum all the data with the same id ..."*

Create a new *List* to contain the merged *Product* values.
Traverse *products*, and then sub-traverse the remaining entries, from *i + 1*.
Merge the *Product* values, and add to the new *List*, if it doesn't already contain the *id*.

```java
List<Product> l = new ArrayList<>();
Product p, t;
int i, j, k, n = products.size(), m;
boolean b;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    p = products.get(i);
    for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
        if (p.getId() == (t = products.get(j)).getId()) {
            p.setPrice(p.getPrice() + t.getPrice());
            p.setQuantity(p.getQuantity() + t.getQuantity());
        }
    b = false;
    for (k = 0, m = l.size(); k < m; k++)
        if (l.get(k).getId() == p.getId()) {
            b = true;
            break;
        }
    if (!b) l.add(p);
}
```

To simplify the process, provide a *method* to merge the values.

```java
class Product {
    ...
    void merge(Product p) {
        price += p.getPrice();
        quantity += p.getQuantity();
    }
    ...
}
```

```java
for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
    if (p.getId() == (t = products.get(j)).getId())
        p.merge(t);
```

Alternately, encapsulate the *ArrayList* class, and implement a *merge* method.

```java
class ProductList extends ArrayList<Product> {
    @Override
    public boolean add(Product product) {
        return merge(product);
    }

    boolean merge(Product p) {
        for (Product v : this)
            if (p.getId() == v.getId()) {
                v.setPrice(p.getPrice() + v.getPrice());
                v.setQuantity(p.getQuantity() + v.getQuantity());
                return true;
            }
        return super.add(p);
    }
}
```

```java
ProductList products = new ProductList();
products.add(new Product(1, "x", 100, 4));
products.add(new Product(4, "y", 200, 2));
products.add(new Product(4, "y", 50, 5));
products.add(new Product(8, "k", 50, 1));
products.add(new Product(10, "m", 1000, 1));
products.add(new Product(1, "x", 100, 1));
```

Output

```
1, x, 200.0, 5
4, y, 250.0, 7
8, k, 50.0, 1
10, m, 1000.0, 1
```

If you did want to use a *stream*, utilize the *[Collectors#toMap](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function))* method.
And, populate an *ArrayList* instance, from the *[collectingAndThen](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#collectingAndThen(java.util.stream.Collector,java.util.function.Function))* method; a somewhat un-intuitive step.

```java
List<Product> l
    = products.stream()
              .collect(
                  Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                      Collectors.toMap(
                          Product::getId,
                          x -> x,
                          (a, b) -> {
                              Product p = new Product();
                              p.merge(b);
                              return p;
                          }),
                      x -> new ArrayList<>(x.values())));
```